# Printing cheques in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am investigating SSRS 2005 as a possible reporting solution for a client and one of my requirements is to print cheques. Is the only way to do this to create a report in SSRS with the dimensions of the cheque with the data fields positioned properly or is there a better way of doing this?  I have googled this problem but I am getting a lot of results for 'checkboxes', 'checking SSRS', and so on so that has been no help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this could be done, and it would probably work pretty well. But SSRS isn't an ideal answer: printing from a web report is subject to the differences in browsers and their page setups & margins. Generating a .pdf and then printing seems like more steps than desirable.

If you decide to go ahead with this, use Rectangles: they try to hold their positions, even when the size of contents change. Also, set the CanGrow property to False everywhere.

Comment: The report isn't being displayed in a browser so that isn't of much concern.  What I did was scanned a image of the check, imported it into the report and embedded it within a list.  Then it was just a matter of positioning the fields properly.  Thanks for the feedback.